# How to store and retrieve image in orientdb using java?

Tags: orientdb

Hi I am new to OrientDB and I search about this in google and I could find this.

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Binary-Data.html.

May be this question is not a valid but I have a doubt what will be type of element which will store binary data.

1.if we are trying to save image as Schema Full property?

2 if we are trying to save image as Schema less property?

As mentioned in above document.

```
ODocument doc = new ODocument();
doc.field("binary", "Binary data".getBytes());
doc.save();
```

where will 'doc' will get saved?

Would it possible to give some example on how to save image/binary data and retrieve it.

Comment: Hi, which version are you using?

Comment: Hi Idacrema, I am using 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

They binary data type for binary types is OType.BINARY

If you don't specify a class for the document, it will be saved in the "default" cluster. Then you can query it with `SELECT FROM cluster:default WHERE ...`

BUT I strongly discourage you from doing it, please also consider that in v 3.0 automatic save to the default cluster no longer supported (but you can still do `doc.save("default")` explicitly)

In general it's much better to create a specific class and save your docs there, eg.

```
//create the schema only the first time of course
OClass class = db.getMetadata().getSchema().createClass("Image"); 
class.createProperty("binary", OType.BINARY); // if you want it schemaful

ODocument doc = db.newInstance("Image")
doc.field("binary", "Binary data".getBytes());
doc.save();
```